# Unable to run Django project with python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

I am new my first clone blog project in Django by trying:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I see the following output:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 19, 2020 - 13:15:32
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
Git
GitHub
Create Repository
Initialize /home/user/Desktop/project with a Git repository
Create repository .............................etc
```

I can't access it in a browser via http://127.0.0.1:8000, instead it is showing the standard Firefox 'Unable to connect' error page:

[image: unable to connect error page]

The text says:

> **Unable to connect**
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

***Added image after executing command said by sir:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTu4s.png)***

this is my project : [my project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YbU6UV35V_ZxPnWsRcl_phIbnl7V7WbW)

Comment: Please show us some code. Did you follow the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) or is this entirely different project?

Comment: How much code did you write while on this project? Did this happen at the start (few lines of code) or is this a final stage (a lot of code)? Would you mind going through the first stage of django project [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) just to see if you encounter the same problems? If you do, it might not to do anything with the code but your local environment.

Comment: Try to execute some commands: `py manage.py check` or  `py manage.py sqlmigrate` or  `py manage.py makemigrations` or `py manage.py migrate`. If you find something suspicious, post it here.

Comment: sir it is the final stage (a lot of code) no at the the first stage it was working  and also showed a rocket sign with message" it worked ! "sir now at the last stage it is not working

Comment: sir, after executing the commands said by you the output picture is added to my question still when i copy paste the http://127.0.0.1:8000/ it is showing the same

Comment: can you send the link of your Entire project

Comment: sir i have added my whole project at the end off my question hope you will reply soon

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YbU6UV35V_ZxPnWsRcl_phIbnl7V7WbW